# Bundle not working (getArguments() always null) [Android]

Tags: android, arguments, bundle

My code was working few hours ago but not anymore, I can't see what is the reason.

Here is my listener where I change fragment after a click :

CustomMarkRow.java

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("id", CustomMarkRow.this.mark.getId());
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = CustomMarkRow.this.fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();                       activity.getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(CustomMarkRow.this.positionTab);
    EditMarkFragment fragment = new EditMarkFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment,"2");
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

At this moment, fragment.getArguments() contains what I put inside :

```
{android.os.Bundle@3644} "Bundle[{id=1}]"
```

In my second file : 
EditMarkFragment.java

```
public class EditMarkFragment extends Fragment {
    public View view;

    public EditMarkFragment(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        this.view = inflater.inflate(getResources().getIdentifier("edit_mark", "layout",container.getContext().getPackageName()), container, false);

        if(this.getArguments()==null){ // always null
            ...
        }

        return this.view
}
```

getArguments() always return null here, What is bad in this sample ?

*** edit ***
Here is my launcher class :

```
public class Launcher extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

private HomeFragment frag1 = new HomeFragment();
private EditMarkFragment frag2  = new EditMarkFragment();
private MarkListFragment frag3 = new MarkListFragment();
private EditCategoryFragment frag4 = new EditCategoryFragment();
private CategoryListFragment frag5 = new CategoryListFragment();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.launcher);

    //Configuration de la barre d'onglet

    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = getActionBar().newTab().setTabListener(this).setTag("1").setText("Home"); //.setIcon(R.drawable.homew);
    getActionBar().addTab(tab1);

    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = getActionBar().newTab().setTabListener(this).setTag("2").setText("New Mark"); //.setIcon(R.drawable.addw);
    getActionBar().addTab(tab2);

    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = getActionBar().newTab().setTabListener(this).setTag("3").setText("My Marks"); //.setIcon(R.drawable.listw);
    getActionBar().addTab(tab3);

    ActionBar.Tab tab4 = getActionBar().newTab().setTabListener(this).setTag("4").setText("New Category"); //.setIcon(R.drawable.categoryw);
    getActionBar().addTab(tab4);

    ActionBar.Tab tab5 = getActionBar().newTab().setTabListener(this).setTag("5").setText("Categories"); //.setIcon(R.drawable.categoryw);
    getActionBar().addTab(tab5);

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    if(tab.getTag().equals("1")){
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag1);
    }
    else if(tab.getTag().equals("2")){
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag2);
    }
    else if(tab.getTag().equals("3")){
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag3);
    }
    else if(tab.getTag().equals("4")){
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag4);
    }
    else if(tab.getTag().equals("5")){
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag5);
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    if(tab.getTag().equals("1")){
        ft.remove(frag1);
    }
    else if(tab.getTag().equals("2")){
        ft.remove(frag2);
    }
    else if(tab.getTag().equals("3")){
        ft.remove(frag3);
    } else if(tab.getTag().equals("4")){
        ft.remove(frag4);
    }
 else if(tab.getTag().equals("5")){
    ft.remove(frag5);
}
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

}
}
```

Comment: Is this the whole source code? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong and I'm wondering if you store _null_ within arguments somewhere else?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but *please* get rid of `static` from your `view` data member. Do not put widgets in static data members, as you will wind up with memory leaks.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for the advice !

Comment: @harism there is nothing between the first line of onCreateView and my "if"  if it is what you mean. When I debug, in each line, the getArguments() value is "null".

Comment: Are you sure that you are not creating an `EditMarkFragment` anywhere else, and it's that case where you are running into the `null` `Bundle`?

Comment: Yes i'm sure... The fragment is just called at the beggining in my "launcher" class to be associated to the action bar tab, and then in this listener @CommonsWare

Comment: "Yes i'm sure" -- not according to your comment. Your comment indicates that you are creating an `EditMarkFragment` in two places ("at the beggining", "in this listener"). You may wish to edit your question to show the "at the beggining" code.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, I just added it, even if this part of the code didn't change  recently. Do you thing it is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your `onClick()` code is creating an arguments `Bundle`, your `onCreate()` is not. If *that* edition of your fragment calls `getArguments()`, the method will return `null`.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment sorry, my launcher file just allows me to manage action bar tabs (actually each tabs contains one fragment). In one of this fragments, I have this OnClick() method creating an argument, which I would like to get in another fragment (so in another tab) called EditMarkFragment. How can I do to get this argument there ? I can't understand why It worked few hours ago and not anymore, and don't see what make it wrong. Can you explain me more how could I fix it ?

Comment: "I don't really understand your comment sorry" -- in your edit, in the code, you have `private EditMarkFragment frag2  = new EditMarkFragment();`. You are not calling `setArguments()` on *this instance* of `EditMarkFragment` in any of the code in your question. When *this instance* of `EditMarkFragment` attempts to call `getArguments()`, it will get `null` as a response. Hence, *this instance* of `EditMarkFragment` will crash in `onCreateView()`. Either get rid of *this instance* of `EditMarkFragment`, or give it a `Bundle`, or have `onCreateView()` handle a `null` arguments `Bundle`.

Comment: I understand now, You're absolutly right ! Thank you very much @CommonsWare , I will fix it right now.

Comment: @Redouane B.  how do you solved it?

Answer (score -1):

1-Update your EditMark fragment with as follows:-

```
public class EditMarkFragment extends Fragment { 
public static View view;

 public static EditMarkFragment newInstance(int id) {
    EditMarkFragment fragment = new EditMarkFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("id", id);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.view = inflater.inflate(getResources().getIdentifier("edit_mark", "layout",container.getContext().getPackageName()), container, false);

  int id=getArguments.getInt("id");

    return this.view}
```

2- Inside CustomMarkRow update your code as :-

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = CustomMarkRow.this.fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();                       activity.getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(CustomMarkRow.this.positionTab);
    EditMarkFragment fragment =  EditMarkFragment.newInstance(CustomMarkRow.this.mark.getId()) ;
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment,"2");
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Try this,hope this will hep you.

Comment: It doesn't work @AdarshYadav , getArguments() also null :/ but thank you for your attempt.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting id from CustomMarkRow.this.mark.getId() ? If not then please debug and test.

Comment: Yes if I print fragment.getArguments() I have : {android.os.Bundle@3644} "Bundle[{id=1}]"

Comment: As per your code everything looks good, If it's not working then why don't way by useing Interface or http://square.github.io/otto/ for communication between fragments.